# How do you make actions have different end frames?

Tags: animation

I need to make different animations for a unity player controller. I am making different animations but when I set the end frame of one, it sets the end frame of all of the actions. Is there a way to make actions have different end frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Timeline* end frame will determine the end of the previsualized and rendered animation (1), it won't determine the length of the actions. The action length will be determined by the first and last keyframe of the action (2):

[image]

If you want to play an action that goes beyond the end frame you can use the <kbd>P</kbd> key (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to exit):

[image]